# What's wrong with this wpdb query?

Tags: wp-query, wpdb

I want to select some tags with the same term_group, I tested it in phpadmin, the query get the correct result, but once add $wpdb flavor, it returns an empty array. Any advice?

```
$primary_tag_id = // a function to return term_group, result is 3, comfirmed
    $terms = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT name
            FROM $wpdb->wp_terms
            WHERE term_group = %d
            ORDER BY name ASC", $primary_tag_id
            ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it worked for me:

```
    global $wpdb;
    $terms = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT name
            FROM {$wpdb->terms}
            WHERE term_group = %d
            ORDER BY name ASC", primary_tag_id
            ));
```

What you are after is `$wpdb->terms` not `$wpdb->wp_terms`